# Running a mysql query from phpmyadmin only changed 1 record. Tried ssh but same issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query to combine fields from one table to another table in the same mysql database.

I tried to execute in phpmyadmin and only changes 1 record (but does it correctly)

After research i found that it should not be done in phpmyadmin. So the only other way i know how was in ssh. Im running putty on my windows 8 pc and i can login to my server then i can log into mysql database. When running the query it still only changes on row.

So then i started looking at php's but not sure that's what i need to do. I would assume i could just run this query to go through entire table but maybe im missing something.

Here is the query im running.

```
INSERT INTO appfilter2 
SELECT userapps.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(userapps.activity, '/',userapps.class)) AS activity 
FROM userapps
```

How can i simply run this query to fill my appfilter2 table with all concatenated entries from userapps?

Comment: note that group_concat is by default limited to 1024 characters. If your activity/class stuff exceeds that, you're going to end up with a truncated record. And generally speaking, you should never be storing "csv" data in a single field. that defeats the purpose of using a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SELECT query is missing a GROUP BY clause. Probably you mean:

```
INSERT INTO appfilter2 
SELECT userapps.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(userapps.activity, '/',userapps.class)) AS activity 
FROM userapps
GROUP BY userapps.name
```

Comment: Should i run that in phpmyadmin or ssh?

Comment: Doesn't matter. By the way, your database design seems quite flawed.

Comment: I know :( I am somewhat new to sql and doing the best I can. really need to read up and get educated instead of shooting in dark. If i post my original table and goal for the table you you suggest what i should be doing?

Comment: Yes, post your design and what you are trying to do with it, and tag it as a DESIGN problem.

Comment: Thanks i posted here yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873755/optimize-mysql-table-structure-with-millions-of-records