# Optimize MySQL table structure with millions of records

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, I am new to MySQL and SQL in general. I use sql in my access databases and aspx web pages but I don't think i'm being very efficient with it. Below is my current Mysql table and my end result. Currently I feel I am doing way too much to get the results i want.

So my question is what is the best way to optimize this table? The table is filled from hundreds of android devices sending the apps they have installed on their devices. I am collecting this info and running a count on how many times they showed up to see which are the most popular.

Right now i have accumulated over 3 million rows and I am exporting this table and importing to access. I then run two queries in access to get my count and export to excel to create the report below.

The unique identifier is the activity and class name combined with /
That is how i determine my counts

I know this question might be considered a discussion but really to answer the question i would just like to know the structure i should be using in my base table.

I know i don't even have an index setup but not sure which field could do it?

If this question is considered a discussion i will take it down right away.

[image: original table]

[image: End result]

Based on the recommendations i added a index shown below and ran the following query to get the data i needed. Did i add the index correctly? What about a primary key? do i just add an auto generated one?

```
SELECT COUNT( name ) , CONCAT( userapps.activity,  '/', userapps.class ) 
FROM userapps
GROUP BY name
```

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason to transfer into Access before generating the query?  MySQL can do that directly and you don't even need Access to store anything.

Comment: An index on activity + class and using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` would be a good start.

Comment: well i actually just started running the queries i was doing in access in mysql. it does work better. However that is what prompted this question. I was told my design was quite flawed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870410/running-a-mysql-query-from-phpmyadmin-only-changed-1-record-tried-ssh-but-same?noredirect=1#comment38626428_24870410

Comment: You should read on normalization. Your table should have a primary key, and you should add the proper indexes to your table. Other than that, MySQL can handle 3 millions of rows (and more) without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I updated the question with my progress and wanted to get clarification on a couple things